# Is There a way to keep focus on a different element when clicking submit button in Selenium webdriver

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver and have a list where I need one element to remain selected when I submit.

But when I find the element and click it the focus shifts to the button so item is not selected anymore. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you post some codes? As I am not sure what exactly you are looking for. Does the focus change to a button when you click the list element?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing Enter key to input field:

```
el.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Or just:

```
el.submit();
```

Comment: its just a list you need to highlight in so enter won't work and I tried submit but didn't work I found a different way around thanks though. I just kinda skipped the dialog box